# How can I remove all rows except the last 20 occurances for a specific value in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a postgres database collecting MQTT broadcasts.
One table contains all the broadcast and is growning rapidly.
The table has a column contaning the unit where the broadcast comes from.
My table doesn't have any id (primary key), can I assume the first found records are the oldest?
Now, I want to keep only the last 3 broadcasts, or so, for each unit, i.e. the last 3 broadcast from unit 100, the last 3 broadcast from unit 101 and so on. Is it possible without a id key?

```
node                namespace               unit          beacondata
rpi-b827eb5cc1c3    5c8554575f873f8b3054    102           {"json data"}
rpi-b827eb5cc1c3    5c8554575f873f8b3054    102           {"json data"}
rpi-b827ebf0ab49    5c8554575f873f8b3054    102           {"json data"}
rpi-b827ebf0ab49    5c8554575f873f8b3054    102           {"json data"}
rpi-b827ebf0ab49    5c8554575f873f8b3054    102           {"json data"}
rpi-b827eb5cc1c3    5c8554575f873f8b3054    100           {"json data"}
rpi-b827eb5cc1c3    5c8554575f873f8b3054    100           {"json data"}
rpi-b827eb5cc1c3    5c8554575f873f8b3054    101           {"json data"}
rpi-b827ebf0ab49    5c8554575f873f8b3054    101           {"json data"}
rpi-b827ebf0ab49    5c8554575f873f8b3054    100           {"json data"}
rpi-b827ebf0ab49    5c8554575f873f8b3054    100           {"json data"}
rpi-b827ebf0ab49    5c8554575f873f8b3054    100           {"json data"}  
rpi-b827eb5cc1c3    5c8554575f873f8b3054    102           {"json data"}
rpi-b827ebf0ab49    5c8554575f873f8b3054    101           {"json data"}
rpi-b827ebf0ab49    5c8554575f873f8b3054    101           {"json data"}  
rpi-b827ebf0ab49    5c8554575f873f8b3054    102           {"json data"}  
rpi-b827ebf0ab49    5c8554575f873f8b3054    101           {"json data"}  
rpi-b827eb5cc1c3    5c8554575f873f8b3054    100           {"json data"}  
rpi-b827ebf0ab49    5c8554575f873f8b3054    102           {"json data"}  
rpi-b827eb5cc1c3    5c8554575f873f8b3054    102           {"json data"}  
rpi-b827eb5cc1c3    5c8554575f873f8b3054    101           {"json data"}  
rpi-b827eb5cc1c3    5c8554575f873f8b3054    100           {"json data"}
```

All columns are string except for beacondata, it's json. There are no id or primary key in this table.

Later on there will be hundreds of units an thousands of broadcasts...

Comment: You can assume that the rows with the oldest timestamp are the oldest

Comment: Share your table structure and some sample data and your desired results as your explanation of your data isn't making it very clear. If you can't identify a unique record and how it's ordered while you are looking at the data, how would we know with just an explanation. Please explain how you would determing "Oldest". Relying on the order that the records are returned from a SELECT statement is 100% not going to cut it as a table has no inherent ordering.

Comment: Oldest is the broadcast last sent to the table.

Comment: I thought SELECT returning records in a older to new order by defaut. Now I see I can't rely on that. The json data contains a unix datestamp, but perhaps it's difficult and timecomsuming to retrieve that. Perhaps an id key is a must...
Cyber

Comment: If you need to order the data, I would strongly recommend adding in either a `SERIAL/BIGSERIAL` or `TIMESTAMP` (possibly `WITH TIMEZONE`) with a default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Doing this now, you'll be able to assume that after 20 more records go in, that the data will sort reliably.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't** assume the first found records are the oldest. The data returned is NOT ORDERED, unless you explicitly specify `ORDER BY`.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-concepts.html

> it is important to remember that SQL does not guarantee the order of
>   the rows within the table in any way (although they can be explicitly
>   sorted for display).

Without clear way defining the order of insertion (PK on `SERIAL` or timestamp attribute) - you have no reliable way.

The attempt could be done by monkey strategy:

1. `alter table ... set (autovacuum_enabled=0)`
2. `select *, row_number() over (partition by node,namespace,unit order by ctid) from ...` query from above `where row_number <=3`
3. periodically stright after the data deletion, `lock table` and `create table as select * from` to rebuild the data and collapse unused space (you can't use vacuum, because it can't be run in transaction)

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added an id to the table and tried your suggestion above but I'm new in database handling and i cant get it to work: SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY node, namespace, unit ORDER by id) FROM broadcast WHERE row_number <= 3; I get error complaining on the last row_number. So I assume I missed something obvious in the last part?

Comment: Finally I got it right:   `DELETE FROM broadcast WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM (SELECT id, unit, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY unit ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn FROM broadcast GROUP BY id, unit) AS t WHERE rn <= 3 ORDER BY rn, id); `